# Reading php via buffered reader... how can I distinguish change of lines?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read a php file with BufferedReader in my Android app.
but my reader reads < /p> or < /br> as text not line change...
my code is like this

```
            HttpEntity entityResponse = res.getEntity();
            InputStream im = entityResponse.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(im, HTTP.UTF_8));

            String tmp = "";
            while((tmp = reader.readLine())!= null)
            {
                if(tmp != null)
                {
                    total1.add(tmp);
                    Log.d("testq", "total1."+i+" "+tmp);
                    tmp = reader.readLine();
                    total2.add(tmp);
                    Log.d("testq", "total2."+i+" "+tmp);
                    tmp = reader.readLine();
                    total3.add(tmp);
                    Log.d("testq", "total3."+i+" "+tmp);
                    tmp = reader.readLine();
                    total4.add(tmp);
                    Log.d("testq", "total4."+i+" "+tmp);
                    tmp = reader.readLine();
                    total5.add(tmp);
                    Log.d("testq", "total5."+i+" "+tmp);
                    tmp = reader.readLine();
                    total6.add(tmp);
                    Log.d("testq", "total6."+i+" "+tmp);
                }
            }
```

the reason I have 6 ArrayList of strings is because the six lines are a set of data in my case.
But when I check the data inside,

```
02-22 15:55:39.557: D/testq(2030): total1.0 2</p>0</p>upload/Ww2016. 2. 22. 3:55:16.png</p>Qq</p>ee</p></p>
02-22 15:55:39.557: D/testq(2030): total2.0 null
02-22 15:55:39.557: D/testq(2030): total3.0 null
02-22 15:55:39.557: D/testq(2030): total4.0 null
02-22 15:55:39.557: D/testq(2030): total5.0 null
02-22 15:55:39.557: D/testq(2030): total6.0 null
```

while it should be

```
total1.0 - 2
total2.0 - 0
total3.0 - upload/Ww2016. 2. 22. 3:55:16.png
total4.0 - qq
total5.0 - ee
total6.0 - null
```

how can I properly readout those < /p>s??

Answer (score 0):

Well `</p>` isn't a linebreak, so there's no reason it would read it as one.  BufferedReader knows nothing about html.  If all you need to worry about is `</p>` and `</br>`, then you can just use `string.split()` to break the data into parts.  But really, unless you're screen scraping a website you don't control you'd be far better off sending down a JSON or XML object than parsing html.